After using B2C for authentication, I want to ask the Browser at what time the b2c cookie will be set?
I'm trying to use Azure AD B2C for authentication for my app. However, understanding when it is set-cookie for the browser seems difficult.
I tried to use the B2C API to authenticate login, but it seems that it only supports ROPC, but not using user flow Sign In. Is the moment it is set-cookie for the browser is the moment B2C returns the code to the browser side?

The cookie is set when the user finishes authentication with Azure AD B2C. Before the redirect back to your application.
So if the sequence of operations is like this:

User clicks Login button in your application
Your application redirects user to authenticate with AAD B2C
User enters their credentials on AAD B2C login page
User goes through MFA etc.
AAD B2C redirects user back to your application

The cookie would be issued by AAD B2C between steps 4 and 5. It is sent to the user's browser and stored there.
